# Querying for multiple valules in array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have an Order record that looks like:

```
{   cust_id : 5     , ordered_pdts : [ 1,2,3 ] }
```

I have Vendors collection. Each vendor record has a list of products the vendor maintains:

```
{   vendor_id : 342     , pdts : [ 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 7, 3 ] }
```

When an order is placed, I need to find the vendors who have ALL the products listed in the Order.

Can this be done with a query operation or Aggregation Framework?

Answer (score 3):

You can try with this query :

```
db.Vendor.find({'pdts' : {$all : [1,2,3]}})
```